# References of a lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need a reference for the following lemma. Thanks

Let $G$ be a finite group such that $Z(G)=1$. Suppose that $H,K$ are two distinct maximal subgroup of $G$ which are abelian.
Then $H \cap K=1$.

Comment: The two subgroups generate the entire group, and anything in the intersection commutes with everything in both of them, hence with everything in the group.